# Generate a new xml from csv data using python

Tags: python, xml

I want to generate the below xml. any leads?

```
CSV data   
id,value,
1,10
2,20

<root>  
    <xs:sample name="id">
            <xs:final>
                <xs:id>1</xs:id>
            </xs:final>
            <xs:new base="xs:string">
                <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
            </xs:new>
    </xs:sample>    
    <xs:sample name="id">
            <xs:final>
                <xs:id>2</xs:id>
            </xs:final>
            <xs:new base="xs:string">
                <xs:maxLength value="20"/>
            </xs:new>
    </xs:sample>    
</root>
```

I have used lxml.etree, but the output xml structure is coming different.

I dont want to hardcode the values as I want to loop with in the csv

sample code, i have used :

```
import csv
import lxml.etree as ET
headers = ['id','value']
root = ET.Element("root")
xssample = ET.SubElement(root, "xssample")
xsfinal = ET.SubElement(xssample, "xsfinal")
xsnew = ET.SubElement(xssample, "xsnew")
xsid = ET.SubElement(xsfinal, "xsid")
xsmaxlength = ET.SubElement(xsnew, "xsmaxlength")

filename = 'sample.csv'

with open(filename) as f:
    next(f)                             # SKIP HEADER
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)

    for row in csvreader:        
        for x in range(len(headers)): 
            data = ET.SubElement(root, "xssample", {'name':headers[x]})
            for col in range(len(headers)):
                node = ET.SubElement(data, headers[col]).text = str(row[col])

# SAVE XML TO FILE
tree_out = (ET.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding="UTF-8"))

# OUTPUTTING XML CONTENT TO FILE
with open('Output.xml', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(tree_out)
```

Output structure is different:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <root>
      <xssample>
        <xsfinal>
          <xsid/>
        </xsfinal>
        <xsnew>
          <xsmaxlength/>
        </xsnew>
      </xssample>
      <xssample name="id">
        <id>1</id>
        <value>10</value>
      </xssample>
      <xssample name="value">
        <id>1</id>
        <value>10</value>
      </xssample>
      <xssample name="id">
        <id>2</id>
        <value>20</value>
      </xssample>
      <xssample name="value">
        <id>2</id>
        <value>20</value>
      </xssample>
    </root>
```

I am not able to change the tags correctly. can anyone point the issue here.

Comment: Show your code attempts

Comment: added the sample code

Comment: So what error/problem you have?

Comment: the tags are coming only for the first set and the values are not getting populated. the values are coming in the second set but the tag were missing. Can you point out the issue in the code.

Comment: You code produces rather a different output than you've described.

Comment: I added the same output just that I typed it and removed the name issue. However you can now find the output in the output section. The name issue is coming because of data = ET.SubElement(root, "xssample", {'name':headers[x]}), so I ignored. Is there any issue with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build your XML manually:

```
import pandas as pd

result = ''
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   result += '''<xs:sample name="id"><xs:final><xs:id>{}</xs:id></xs:final><xs:new base="xs:string"><xs:maxLength value="{}"/></xs:new></xs:sample>'''.format(int(row['id']), int(row['value']))
root = '<root>{}</root>'.format(result)
```

Output:

```
<root><xs:sample name="id"><xs:final><xs:id>1</xs:id></xs:final><xs:new base="xs:string"><xs:maxLength value="10"/></xs:new></xs:sample><xs:sample name="id"><xs:final><xs:id>2</xs:id></xs:final><xs:new base="xs:string"><xs:maxLength value="20"/></xs:new></xs:sample></root>
```

Comment: Thank you Alderven. I will try this but is it possible to automatically do it with lxml.etree?

Comment: `xs:` part will be lost in this case. Is it critical for you to have `xs:` prefixes in XML?

Comment: Yes Alderven.. I also have that issue